# Put a commit on top of a branch, regardless of history

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have two branches, master and release, and I'm trying to write a github-action that can pull everything from master, run a build command and then push the change to the release branch without filling the history with the commits from master.

It works when I do this manually using the commands below:

```
git checkout release
git merge master --no-commit --squash
ionic build --prod
git commit -m "Build 1.x"
```

This doesn't bring up any merge conflicts and just works. Attempting it in the action causes merge conflicts or an unrelated history error. Rebasing works but it doesn't give me the clean history in the release branch that I'm after to make it easy to roll back in case of issues.

I've also attempted using an orphan branch and rebasing that onto the release branch but that clears all history in the release branch. I thought I might be able to take the single commit generated in that branch and put it on top of release, but I can't find a command to do that.

Here is what I initially attempted:

```yaml
    name: Build
    branches: [ master ]

    workflow_dispatch:

    jobs:
      build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        steps:

          - uses: actions/checkout@v2
              with:
                ref: release

          - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
          - uses: coturiv/setup-ionic@v1

          - name: Install node Packages
              run : npm i

          - name: Get code changes for build
              run: |
               git fetch
               git checkout master
               git checkout release
               git rebase -s ours master release

          - name: Build
              run: ionic build --prod

          - name: Initialise Commit
             run: | 
             git config user.email "<ommitted>"
             git config user.name "<ommitted>"
             git add www/
             git commit -m "Build - $GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER"
      
         - name: Push Build
             run: git push --force
```

This is what I've currently got:

```yaml
    name: Build

    on:
      push:
        branches: [ master ]

      workflow_dispatch:

    jobs:
      build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        steps:

          - uses: actions/checkout@v2
            with:
              ref: release

          - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
          - uses: coturiv/setup-ionic@v1

          - name: Install node Packages
            run: npm i

          - name: Initialise Git Config
            run: |
              git config user.email "simon@ineedsurgery.com"
              git config user.name "simon"

          - name: Get code changes for build
            run: |
              git fetch
              git checkout master
              git pull

          - name: Create temporary build branch
            run: |
              git checkout --orphan build-temp

          - name: Build
            run: |
              ionic build --prod
              git add --all
              git commit -m "Build - $GITHUB_RUN_ID"

          - name: Rebase build commit
            run: |
              git checkout release
              git pull
              git rebase -s ours build-temp release
              git branch build-temp -d
      
          - name: Push Build
            run: git push --force
```

Thanks for the help and I hope my question is clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a merge argument that allows me to achieve what I'm looking for

```
--allow-unrelated-histories
```

It was well hidden in the documentation. The cherrypick answer looked good for manually editing branches but as it's automated, it didn't work.

This was my final code:

```html
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: Build

# Controls when the action will run. 
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
  push:
    branches: [ dev ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it

      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: release

      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      - uses: coturiv/setup-ionic@v1

      - name: Install node Packages
        run: npm i

      - name: Initialise Git Config
        run: |
          git config user.email "blah"
          git config user.name "blah"

      - name: Get code changes for build
        run: |
          git fetch
          git checkout dev
          git pull
      
      - name: Checkout release and merge
        run: |
          git checkout release
          git pull
          git merge dev --squash --no-commit --allow-unrelated-histories -X theirs
          git reset

      - name: Build
        run: |
          ionic build --prod
          git add --all
          git commit -m "Build - $GITHUB_RUN_ID"
      
      - name: Push Build
        run: git push --force
```

Answer (score 0):

"I thought I might be able to take the single commit generated in that branch and put it on top of release, but I can't find a command to do that."

Have you tried `git cherrypick`? This essentially allows you to pick a single commit from a branch and apply it to another, regardless of history (as you've wished for in your title). It's described [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/cherry-pick).

From that tutorial:

"To demonstrate how to use `git cherry-pick` let us assume we have a repository with the following branch state:

```
a - b - c - d   Master
     \
       e - f - g Feature
```

`git cherry-pick` usage is straight forward and can be executed like:

```
git cherry-pick commitSha
```

In this example commitSha is a commit reference. You can find a commit reference by using `git log`. In this example we have constructed lets say we wanted to use commit `f` in `master`. First we ensure that we are working on the `master` branch.

```
git checkout master
```

Then we execute the `cherry-pick` with the following command:

```
git cherry-pick f
```

Once executed our Git history will look like:

```
a - b - c - d - f   Master
     \
       e - f - g Feature
```

The `f` commit has been successfully picked into the master branch."